# Syntax error Line 11: SyntaxError: bad input ('print')

Tags: python

I'm new to python. So far it looks very basic and understandable. I decided to re-write the hole script and now its giving me
Line 11: SyntaxError: bad input ('print')
Any idea why Print would be a Syntax Error?

NOTE: I'm having troubles trying to paste the code in with "

```
#START OF CALCULATOR CODE#
print(input("Thank you for calling how may I help you?"))
name = input("Okay Whats your name?")
print (input("Thank you " + name + " And can I have your number?"))
print (input("Do you live around the 84041 area??"))
if "Yes" or "":
    print "Okay, " + name + " Dilivery time will be 30 mins"
    print (input("Would you like a 12 Inch pizza with that?")
if "Yes" or ""
    print "Okay, " + name + " Your pizza is now being made and will be dilivered to you soon."
    basepizza = 5
    basecharge = 5
    diliveryprice = 6.5
    print ("Okay, Your total cost comes out to",basepizza,diliveryprice,basecharge)
    print "Thank you!"
if "No":
    print int(input("How many inches would you like?")
if inches>12:
    inchprice = 0.5
    inchprice = (inches/2)+inchprice*(inchprice+0.5)
    basecharge = 5.0
    diliveryprice = 6.5
    print ("Okay " + name + " Your total cost comes out to", inchprice,diliveryprice,basecharge)
    print "Thank you!"
else:  
if "No":
    print "Okay, " + name + " Dilivery time will be 45Mins"
    print (input("Would you like a 12 inch pizza with that?")
if "Yes" or "":
    print "Okay, Your pizza is now being made and will be dilivered too you shortly. Thank you!"
    basepizza = 5
    basecharge = 5.0
    diliveryout = 7.5
    print ("Your toal cost is"basepizza,diliveryprice,basecharge)
    print "Thank you!"
if "No":
    print int(input("How many inches would you like?")
if inches>12:
    inchprice = 0.5
    inchprice = (inches/2)+inchprice*(inchprice+0.5)
    basecharge = 5.0
    diliveryout = 7.5
    print ("You're total cost will come out to",inchprice,diliveryout,basecharge)
    print "Thank you!"
#END OF CALCULATOR CODE. ENJOY#
```

[Python syntax error line 11, ON PASTE BIN](http://pastebin.com/7Z6hGAad)

Comment: Please post your code here, not on another site.

Comment: There are a number of problems in that code (for example, `if "Yes" or ""`), you should probably start with a shorter example and get that working before adding to it.

Comment: Look on line 11, you are missing () around your print statement. Guessing this is Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

Lets do the **Syntax errors** first

You are missing a `)` on line 8

You are missing the colon at the end of line 9 (`if...:`)

You are missing a `)` on line 17

at line 25 you can't have an empty `else` block

```
else:  
if "No":
```

You are missing a `)` on line 28

You are missing a `,` on line 34

You are missing a `)` on line 37

---

Now for some more errors:

This expression will always be True

```
if "Yes" or "":
```

You need to assign the result of `input()` to a variable - also don't need the `print`

```
live_close = input("Do you live around the 84041 area??")
if live_close in {"Yes", ""}:
```

etc.

Your logic flow seems flawed, or perhaps you don't realise that nested `if` blocks have to also be nested by indentation.

Comment: Line 10: SyntaxError: bad input (':')
Thats when i add a :

Comment: Ah okay, Thank you this is helping a lot, Sorry I'm a bit new to Python. Been working on this project for 3 Hours cannot understand some of these Syntax errors. Although now I have a Line 6: SyntaxError: bad input (',')
for if live_close in {"Yes", ""}:

Comment: Are you using a really really really old version of Python?

Comment: 2.7 Is that fine or should I update?

Comment: 2.7 is fine. `{"Yes", ""}` is a set literal. I'm not sure why you're getting an error from it

Comment: Hmm could it be the website I'm visualizing it with? http://www.codeskulptor.org/

Comment: I got a new error now. Line 9: SyntaxError: bad input (':')
for (if "Yes" or "") i also tried if "Yes" or "" same error

Comment: Ah..for python2.7 you need to use `raw_input` instead if `input`. Might be a better idea to upgrade to Python3.4 if you can